# How to save jmeter aggregate report by getting all rows to one

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm attempting to save a jmeter aggregate report. the csv file comes as this
[file getting saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztJE4.png)

Is there a way to get the columns as
[expected file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0DlC.png)

If i'm running a heavy load having the aggregated results in one row seems practical. How can i save the file like that.

I have seen a command in JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool as `--aggregate-rows <yes/no>` but it didn't do any change

This is the command i used to generate the file

JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv "agg-cmd2.csv" --input-jtl "result.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport --aggregate-rows yes

Answer (score 0):

You have different labels in your test therefore Aggregate Report displays one row per sampler label.

You can replace these sampler labels with the same value in the .jtl file using i.e. [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) tool like:

```
awk '$3="HTTP Request"' FS=, OFS=, result.jtl > aggregate.jtl
```

Alternatively you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) for the same, it will substitute whatever sampler labels you have with the `HTTP Request` (or whatever synthetic label you choose), the relevant code would be something like:

```
prev.setSampleLabel('HTTP Request')
```

where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see JavaDoc for all possible functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands.